# Building the perfect Distro with Snap

Tags: ubuntu, mate-desktop, distributions, snap

Snap is new package system for creating and installing apps, but its kind of new. I was wondering if the library is robust enough to be the main package manager for a new distro.

Some context: I've been using Ubuntu for a while, as well as Arch and RedHat for my projects, and I wandered across the snap platform. I was wondering if I could create a really lightweight distro that uses snap as the primary package manager, and have apt as a backup. I want to use the GNOME MATE DE, and I guess Debian based, but as much as possible I want to use a snap for dealing with updates and the like. Does snap have enough apps, in the right categories, to make a distro like this useful for regular users (Again for context, I'm a Computer Engineering Student)? Does this Distro already exist? Thanks for the help, I'm mostly looking for a place to start.

Comment: short answer is probably yes you could build this. Long answer on how to with what method is both opinion base and very complex.

Answer (score 1):

This already exists, and is called [Ubuntu Core](https://www.ubuntu.com/core). It's the original purpose of snaps, for a lightweight distro based completely on them. Gives you robust, transactional updates for the entire OS, bootloader to apps. It's mostly targeting the IoT, though, not traditional desktop users.

Comment: I'm mostly looking for a desktop-oriented version, and I don't think that Ubuntu core would be able to handle that, regardless of modification.